# Divisors of a number in Python

Tags: python, division

I've tried to write a peice of  code in python that prints all the divisors of a number including itself. it doesn't work correctly can anyone see why?

```
def divisors(num):

    for x in range (1, num):
        if (num % x) == 0:
            print(x)


print("Divisors of 6 are")

print(divisors(6))
```

Comment: It seems to work for me. Numbers get printed out. I didn't really pay attention to what the numbers actually are. What makes you say it doesn't work correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`range()` excludes the upper bound and therefore should read `range(1, num+1)`.

Answer (score 1):

you can also try this

```
num=int(input("please eenter a number "))
a=[]
for x in range(1,num+1):
if num%x==0:
a.append(x)
print(a)
```